# Не регистрирует новые данные в БД SQLite3, Python

Tags: python, sqlite3

При вводе новых данных в таблицу программа выводит на print что такая запись уже есть, хотя её не может там быть.
вот код:

```
import sqlite3 as sq

db = sq.connect('server.db')
moon = db.cursor()
moon.execute(""" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
login TEXT,
password TEXT,
cash BIGINT)
""")
db.commit()

while True:
    user_login = input('enter the login: ')
    user_password = input('enter the password: ')
    user_cash = int(input('enter the cash: '))

    moon.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    if moon.fetchone() is None:
        moon.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_login, user_password, user_cash))
        db.commit()
        print('Зарегистрировано!')
    else:
        print('Такая запись существует')
```

Если кто знает подскажите почему так происходит, почему не записывается новая запись?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM users"` — ну так вы запрашиваете из базы не «такую» запись, вы запрашиваете ЛЮБУЮ запись, а точнее все записи сразу. Разумеется, если в таблице есть хотя бы одна запись (любая), то fetchone не будет None

Comment: К комментарию выше - а если таблица пустая, то наверное как раз None и возвращается?

Comment: Вместо "SELECT * FROM users" я писал "SELECT login FROM users", "SELECT login, password FROM users" результат тот же самый.

Comment: И все эти запросы по-прежнему возвращают все записи из таблицы

Comment: посмотрите, что вам возвращает `moon.execute("SELECT * FROM users")` а так же, какой результат при этом получается в `moon.fetchone()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3 as sq

db = sq.connect('something.db')
moon = db.cursor()
moon.execute(""" 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
login TEXT,
password TEXT,
cash BIGINT)
""")
db.commit()

while True:
    user_login = input('enter the login: ')

    l = moon.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?", (user_login,))
    is_user = True if l.fetchone() is None else False
    if is_user:
        user_password = input('enter the password: ')
        user_cash = int(input('enter the cash: '))
        moon.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_login, user_password, user_cash))
        db.commit()
        print('Зарегистрировано!')
    else:
        print('Такая запись существует')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо команды

```
moon.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
```

примените

```
moon.execute("SELECT login FROM users WHERE "
             "login = ?", (user_login, ))
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Командой

```
moon.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
```

вы выбираете **все** записи таблицы — значит, когда таблица непустая (и после первой записи она такой и будет), то в следующей команде

```
if moon.fetchone() is None:
```

метод `.fetchone()` будет возвращать первую строку, **а не `None`**. Потому условие `is None` не выполнится (и программа будет продолжаться ветвей `else`).

Нужно выбрать только запись, в которой в поле `login` находится пользователем заданная строка, что я в своем предложении и сделал.

---

*Примечание:*

Ваш цикл *бесконечный.* Нужно его *где-то прервать.*
Например тогда, когда пользователь на ваш вопрос `enter the login:`  только нажмет на клавишу  <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
user_login = input('enter the login: ')    # ваша оригинальная команда
if user_login == '':                       # добавлено
    break                                  # добавлено
```